# populating one checkedlistbox with another (checkedlistbox)

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, checkedlistbox, populate

I am having difficulties populating a checkedlistbox (CLB) based on the selection(s) made in another. It should also be noted that I have a "Select All" checkbox at the top that checks/unchecks all of the items in the first CLB. Here's the code:

```
Private Sub chkSelectAll_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles chkSelectAll.CheckedChanged
    For i As Integer = 0 To clb1.Items.Count - 1
        clb1.SetItemChecked(i, chkSelectAll.Checked)
    Next
    If chkSelectAll.Checked = False Then
        clb2.Items.Clear()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub clb1_ItemCheck(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.ItemCheckEventArgs) Handles clb1.ItemCheck
    Dim i As Integer = clb1.SelectedIndex

    For j As Integer = 0 To al_2.Count - 1
        If i = -1 Then
            For k As Integer = 0 To al_2.Count - 1
                If Not clb2.Items.Contains(al_2(k).sDate) Then
                    clb2.Items.Add(al_2(k).sDate)
                Else : k += 1
                End If
            Next
        ElseIf (e.NewValue = CheckState.Checked And al_2(j).sName = al_1(i)) Then
            clb2.Items.Add(al_2(j).sDate)
        ElseIf (e.NewValue = CheckState.Unchecked And al_2(j).sName = al_1(i)) Then
            clbProdBkups.Items.Remove(al_2(j).sDate)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

The first CLB is populated with an arraylist of values on the button click event. Based on whatever is checked in the first CLB, corresponding values from an arraylist of structures should fill the second CLB. The following code partially works until the "Select All" checkbox is clicked at which point if other values have been selected before "Select All" is checked, the second CLB is filled with the correct number of corresponding values BUT only those of the most recently selected item of the first CLB instead of all of corresponding values of all of the items that were not already selected.

Any insights will be greatly appreciated.

~8th

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have used an Dictionary to map key clb1-items to the corresponding clb2-items.
Have a look at my sample code which runs fine:

```
Private mytable As New Generic.Dictionary(Of String, List(Of String))

    Sub New()
        ' Dieser Aufruf ist für den Windows Form-Designer erforderlich.
        InitializeComponent()

        mytable.Add("Object A", New List(Of String)(New String() {"Object A1", "Object A2", "Object A3"}))
        mytable.Add("Object B", New List(Of String)(New String() {"Object B1", "Object B2", "Object B3"}))
        mytable.Add("Object C", New List(Of String)(New String() {"Object C1", "Object C2", "Object C3"}))
        mytable.Add("Object D", New List(Of String)(New String() {"Object D1", "Object D2", "Object D3"}))
        mytable.Add("Object E", New List(Of String)(New String() {"Object E1", "Object E2", "Object E3"}))

        For Each key As String In mytable.Keys
            Me.clb1.Items.Add(key, False)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub chkSelectAll_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As  System.EventArgs) Handles ChkSelectAll.CheckedChanged
        For i As Int32 = 0 To Me.clb1.Items.Count - 1
            Me.clb1.SetItemChecked(i, ChkSelectAll.Checked)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub clb1_ItemCheck(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.ItemCheckEventArgs) Handles clb1.ItemCheck
        Dim key As String = DirectCast(Me.clb1.Items(e.Index), String)
        If e.NewValue = CheckState.Checked Then
            For Each value As String In mytable(key)
                Me.Clb2.Items.Add(value, False)
            Next
        Else
            For Each value As String In mytable(key)
                Me.Clb2.Items.Remove(value)
            Next
        End If
    End Sub
```

Regards,
Tim

**EDIT**:
When you dont want to use Generics you can use Hashtable and Arraylist instead.
My sample code is almost the same.
Have a look:

```
    Private mytable As New Hashtable()

    Sub New()
        ' Dieser Aufruf ist für den Windows Form-Designer erforderlich.
        InitializeComponent()

        mytable.Add("Object A", New ArrayList(New String() {"Object A1", "Object A2", "Object A3"}))
        mytable.Add("Object B", New ArrayList(New String() {"Object B1", "Object B2", "Object B3"}))
        mytable.Add("Object C", New ArrayList(New String() {"Object C1", "Object C2", "Object C3"}))
        mytable.Add("Object D", New ArrayList(New String() {"Object D1", "Object D2", "Object D3"}))
        mytable.Add("Object E", New ArrayList(New String() {"Object E1", "Object E2", "Object E3"}))

        For Each key As String In mytable.Keys
            Me.clb1.Items.Add(key, False)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub chkSelectAll_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ChkSelectAll.CheckedChanged
        For i As Int32 = 0 To Me.clb1.Items.Count - 1
            Me.clb1.SetItemChecked(i, ChkSelectAll.Checked)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub clb1_ItemCheck(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.ItemCheckEventArgs) Handles clb1.ItemCheck
        Dim key As String = DirectCast(Me.clb1.Items(e.Index), String)
        If e.NewValue = CheckState.Checked Then
            For Each value As String In mytable(key)
                Me.Clb2.Items.Add(value, False)
            Next
        Else
            For Each value As String In mytable(key)
                Me.Clb2.Items.Remove(value)
            Next
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response Tim but unfortunatley this routine is for work and the boss is one that insists that I only use arrays, arraylists, structures, and hashtables "for the sake of consistencey" *grrr*. I am currently in the process of applying your methodology to the tools that I am "allowed" to use. We'll see how it goes from here. ~8th

Comment: You can use a Hashtable and an Arraylist instead of my Dictionary and List(of String). Its almost the same.